# Will the View returned by LayoutInflater.inflate() always also be a ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android

I'm wanting to add a `LinearLayout` programmatically to my screen. When I call `getlayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.whatever, null)`, will the returned `View` always be also a `ViewGroup`? What could it ever return that is not a ViewGroup?

Comment: its a View defined by you as a root View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned view depends on what is defined in the layout as the root view. It can also be a simple view like a `TextView` so it is not necessarily a `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You can check which are `ViewGroups` from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

The basic principle is that `ViewGroup` can contain child `Views`

For example if you inflate layout which has only `ImageView` in it. Then that is a `View`.